# How to check api status in Nuxt.js SSR?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

This screenshot is get api in front-end , so I can check api status in chrome  devtool

[image]

but when i use SSR by `Nuxt.js` , the api request is on server-side , so I can't check api status in the `chrome devtool` ..

Is any good way to check api status ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need to check requests in network tab you can push router to other page and then click go back to previous to see the requsets

but if you check requset in ssr you can get req and res in context asyncdata and check that
check https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/concepts/context-helpers/